# Jade - Displaying object attributes - undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm passing an object into my template. I've confirmed that the object is there:

```
input(type='text', name='cta', class='form-control', value= fdata, required, autofocus)
```

This renders the input with the full object in the input field:

```
{"_id":"54b852bf8128fb7d24723e70","__v":0,"cta":"Example text","logo":"uploads/bd6ef27f219be5bbbd0e4b3b8bb7a1db.jpg"}
```

This, however sets the value as `undefined`:

```
input(type='text', name='cta', class='form-control', value= fdata.cta, required, autofocus)
```

as well as this:

```
input(type='text', name='cta', class='form-control', value= #{fdata.cta}, required, autofocus)
```

Is this normal? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jade doesn’t JSON-encode objects for use in the `value` attribute, so it appears you have a JSON string that you need to parse. You can do it in the template, but wherever `fdata` comes from might be a better bet.

```
input(
    type='text',
    name='cta',
    class='form-control',
    value=JSON.parse(fdata).cta,
    required,
    autofocus)
```